# Get Large JSON from web API

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, serialization

I am using .net Web Api to get data for my data grid. The call is made via ajax call like this

```js
 $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   dataType: 'json',
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   url: ReportURL, // "api/AppData/InvoiceReport/10"
   success: function (mydata) {
     
     console.log(mydata);
     createReportGrid(myData); // this function creates a KENDO grid
   },                
   error: function (error) {
     alert(error);
   }
 });
```

The Web API method Looks like this

```js
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage InvoiceReport(int Id)
{
  // some llogic of data retrieving
  // objReportDataList is of Type List<vmReport>
  // thisstructure contains a DataTable, and 2 more list type  
 return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, objReportDataList);
}
```

These calls work **perfectly** for Rows Count approx **100K** rows

Web Api serializes perfectly. But when the Row Count exceeds **200K** i get **500 internal server error**
The stack traces tells "System-OutOfMemoryException-occured-in-mscorlib-dll"

**NOTE** - I cant use server pagination to get little data only. This Million rows data is working on a ASP.NET Webforms application. We have migrated to MVC pattern and used WebApi for fetching Data but this error is occuring.
**PS** - I have tried **many many solutions**, but helpless

Please Guide me to Get this error removed and my reports get going

Comment: Check the Web.config of the webforms solution. I bet there is a setting there. This sounds like a configuration issue. Apart from the fact this is a ton of data, which you already know.

Comment: i doubt the web.config has any settings that would avoid an out of memory error... though i may be wrong.

Comment: web.config has the json limit set.... i am using JSON.NET to serialize objects. Data is alot i know. when it can produce 200K records, then why not further ??

Comment: can we some how stream this large data from the Web Api ?

Answer (score 4):

you should stream the response. then you can return millions of rows which are sent in chunks.

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage PushStreamContent()
{
    var response = Request.CreateResponse();

    response.Content = 
        new PushStreamContent((stream, content, context) =>
    {
        foreach (var staffMember in _staffMembers)
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, staffMember);
                stream.Flush();
            }
        }
    });

    return response;
}
```

more info here:
http://dblv.github.io/2014/07/02/streaming-web-api/

Answer (score 0):

you can add below in web.config file

```
<configuration> 
   <system.web.extensions>
       <scripting>
           <webServices>
               <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
           </webServices>
       </scripting>
   </system.web.extensions>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I suggest one more thing,
1. return only those columns which is required for you
2. return some alias name for properies eg. EmployeeName = "Ravi", return as a="Ravi" and because this is for your internal use you know what is a

Comment: Or you could restructure it to use a column vs data approach: `{columns: ['name','address','plan','age'], data: [['bob','canada','sorry',32],['john','usa','fantastic',16]]}`